# Trying To Get Data From Server HDD

Tags: fedora, permissions, data-recovery

I had two CentOS 6.5 servers that I was running using the Plesk control panel.

I have moved and decided not to use them no more but just buy my hosting. My new ISP blocks port 80 and the cost is insane to get it unblocked from them.

I took out the server HDD and trying to use a Fedora 12 Live CD to just get the website files backed up.

The issue I'm having is that the folder I need access to are all locked out.

The error says I do not have permissions to view folder. When I go to permissions tab I'm being told I'm not the owner. I'm not good with command lines so is there a way to make myself the owner from the interface?

Comment: How exactly are you accessing the folders? Can you show the results of `mount` command?

Comment: Not using commands. Using a graphic interface on a Fedora 12 live cd. Folder has a X next to it and gives the errors above when trying to open.

Comment: I don't think we can troubleshoot your problem without gathering some data from the terminal.

Comment: Well if i could use the terminal... im sure i wouldn't need help haha. Ill just get an answer someplace else. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your old disks are probably formatted with ext3 or ext4. Both of those filesystems have permissions (unlike, for example, FAT which doesn't). And unfortunately, its not possible to disable permissions on them.

So when you're mounting the old drives (no matter how you do it—on the command line or via double-clicking in the GUI), the system is going to look at the permission data on those drives and check if your user on the livecd has permission. And your livecd user doesn't,

The easiest way to defeat these permissions is to become root. Of course, being root defeats *all* permissions, so its somewhat dangerous. From the command line, I'd suggest something like this:

```
sudo tar czf /path/to/archive.tar.gz /path/to/web-files
```

This will create a .tar.gz of your website files in `archive.tar.gz`. That archive will be made by root (so the permission restrictions will be ignored) and owned by root as well. You can change the owner with `sudo chown new-owner:new-group /path/to/archive.tar.gz` or via the GUI.